# If-else statement causing problems with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

## Update #1 - Clarified question, new working link.

---

### Live link: https://s3.amazonaws.com/bsunproduction/auction/index.html

The problem I'm trying to fix lies with if-else statement for my form buttons on the right column of the page. Scroll down past the header and navigation to see the problem in action. **The issue occurs when I do the following:**

- Click one of the form buttons, click a different form button then deselect the second button clicked before `countup.js` is complete

### The end goal

- When none of the form buttons are selected, the number under "Your bid will be" should just be a string of three hypens `---` to denote no value
- Instead, the numbers for `.new__amount` count down and the HTML becomes the value of the `totalAmount`, which I do not want to happen.

### scripts.js

```
/*-------------------------------------
    STEP ONE: PLACE BID
    --------------------------------------*/

$.ajax({
  url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/4a8eceba",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "json"
}).then(function(spreadsheet) {

  // Print current bid
  var currentBid = parseInt(spreadsheet.result.pop().Bids);
  $(".current__amount").html("$" + currentBid);

  var baseAmount = 0;
  var totalAmount = baseAmount;

  $('.button__form').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).hasClass('is-selected')) {
      $(this).removeClass('is-selected');
      $(".check--one").css("color", "#ccc");
      $(".new__amount").css("margin-left", 10 + "px");
      $(".bids__dollar").addClass("is--hidden");
      totalAmount = parseInt(totalAmount) - parseInt(value);
      console.log("If");
      $('.total__amount').html("---");
    } else {
      $(".button__form").removeClass('is-selected');
      $(this).addClass('is-selected');
      $(".check--one").css("color", "#ffdc00");
      totalAmount = currentBid; // reset the totalAmount to base
      totalAmount = parseInt(totalAmount) + parseInt(value);
      console.log("Else");
      $('.total__amount').html("$" + totalAmount);
      $(".bids__dollar").removeClass("is--hidden");
      $(".new__amount").css("margin-left", 0 + "px");

      /*-------------------------------------
      COUNTUP
      --------------------------------------*/

      $(function() {
        var options = {  
          useEasing: true,
            useGrouping: true,
            separator: '',
            decimal: '',
            prefix: '',
            suffix: ''
        };

        var count = new CountUp("count", 0, totalAmount, 0, 1.5, options);
        count.start();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

### index.html (Just the buttons)

```
<div class="bids__step bids--one">
  <h2>Step One</h2>
  <div class="bids__checkmark">
    <i class="fa fa-check check--one"></i>
  </div>

  <p class="bids__note">Pick one of the amounts below to add to the current bid.</p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button__form button__one" value="10">$10</button>
    <button class="button__form button__two" value="25">$25</button>
    <button class="button__form button__three" value="50">$50</button>
    <button class="button__form button__four" value="100">$100</button>
    <button class="button__form button__five" value="250">$250</button>
    <button class="button__form button__six" value="500">$500</button>
  </div>
  <!-- /.buttons -->

  <div class="bids__amounts">
    <div class="bids__amount bids__current">
      <p class="bids__note">The last bid was</p>
      <h4 class="current__amount">---</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="bids__amount bids__new">
      <p class="bids__note">Your bid will be</p>
      <h4 class="bids__dollar is--hidden">$</h4>
      <h4 class="new__amount total__amount" id="count">---</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /.bids__amount -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.bids__amounts -->
</div>
```

Comment: You should make a JSfiddle.

Comment: @Mark Here's a JSBin: https://jsbin.com/vivexolako/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Sorry, i spend 15 minutes now trying to understand your problem and I still can't. Can you give some more details? Also, in the JSBin, the countup.js is not included. As this is related to the problem, it would be very helpful to have the countup - code included.

Comment: @Gabrielmachts I've clarified the question and added a link, which contains countup.js. Hopefully now you'll be able to see the problem.

Comment: @Mark I have updated the question and provided a working link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to the `if`/`else` conditions.

The issue is that the count up plugin is overwriting the text (since it is still being executed after you set the text in the `if`/`else` conditions).

According to the [CountUp.js documentation](https://github.com/inorganik/CountUp.js), the `.start()` method accepts a function as a callback, which will be executed when the animation ends.

Therefore, the simplest work-around would be to check if there are any selected button elements in the callback. If there aren't any selected elements, then set the text of `.total__amount` to `---`:

```
var count = new CountUp("count", 0, totalAmount, 0, 1.5, options);
count.start(function() {
  if ($('.button__form.is-selected').length === 0) {
    $('.total__amount').text("---");
  }
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could also create an array of `count` objects.

In the snippet below, there is a `counterArray` array which contains each `count` object.

Inside of your `if` statement, use the `.reset()` method on each of the `count` objects in the array ***before*** setting the text of `.total__amount` to `---`:

```
counterArray.forEach(function (count) {
  if (count && count.reset) {
    count.reset();
  }
});

$('.total__amount').text("---");
```

Here is the relevant code and a [**working example here**](https://jsbin.com/bodojibuqu/1/).

<sub>(Irrelevant code removed for brevity)</sub>

```
var baseAmount = 0;
var totalAmount = baseAmount;
var counterArray = [];

$('.button__form').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('is-selected')) {
    // ....

    counterArray.forEach(function (count) {
      if (count && count.reset) {
        count.reset();
      }
    });

    $('.total__amount').text("---");
  } else {
    // ....

    $(function() {
      var options = {};
      var count = new CountUp("count", 0, totalAmount, 0, 1.5, options);
      count.start();
      counterArray.push(count);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The second part of your answer worked like a charm. Just got to wait 10 hours to reward the bounty. The problem with the first answer, despite how simple it was, is that there was a period in time where it would flash the value of `totalAmount` for a few second, then change the text to the placeholder "---" text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple: the countup method keeps running and updating the value even after you reset it to "---".

Fortunately, the solution is very simple as well. Add the following line **before** `$('.total__amount').html("---");` :

```
if (count.typeof == "object") {   // just checking if the count object actually exists.
 count.pauseResume();
 count.reset();
}
```

In order for this to work you have to make the count object globally available. So change this line:

```
  var count = new CountUp("count", 0, totalAmount, 0, 1.5, options);
```

to this: (just remove "var")

```
  count = new CountUp("count", 0, totalAmount, 0, 1.5, options);
```

Compare here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Then you should be good!

Note: The methods of the count object I derived from the countup.js file.